# Xamarin.Forms Grid clicked (gesture recognizer) pass grid text to code behind?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, grid

Basically I have a list view item template that involves a grid with a tap gesture recognizer.

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Handle_Tapped"  />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

When the `Handle_Tapped` is triggered, the page switches and I want to `MessagingCenter` to transmit the name of the grid.

Is this possible, and if so how would I implement it?

Please don't say custom renderer. Please.......

Comment: I think in this case the sender parameter of the Tapped handler would be the Grid (I might be wrong) so you should be able to cast it and then retrieve any property you need

Comment: I tried doing sender. (and letting autocomplete finish it for me) but it only showed the options type, tostring, etc. Nothing really pertaining to Grids.

Comment: Whats a cast @Jason

Comment: you have to cast it to the correct type first.  var grid = (Grid)sender;

Comment: It looks like the gesture recognizers aren't even working in the item template.

Comment: Update the complete ListView code

Comment: Where is Handle_Clicked event in you code it is Handle_Tapped, update your question with more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using MessageCenter unless it is an explicit requirement,
so Instead of giving the tapped event to viewcell give it to the child element of viewcell.

```
<Viewcell> 
       <Grid>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OpenCaseDetails" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            ...
            ...
       </Grid>
</Viewcell>
```

for more you can refer my blog post about interactive Listview at https://adityadeshpandeadi.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/the-more-interactive-listview/

feel free to drop by if you have any further queries. :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend message center?

Comment: I have used messaging center and it sometimes messes up with the subscriptions.
also, messaging center is just a gateway provider, like navigationParameters etc. the main concern should be identifying the sender who is being tapped. what is its object, which you can transmit over.